# How do i put php variables into JSON with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to send back a JSON OBJECT, but the data depends on a $id variable that is send when submitting a AJAX call, how do i use this $id variable inside my JSON string and send it back to JSON.parse()?

This is basically what i would like to do, i am new to JSON

How i would like it to be

```
$id = somenumber;
echo '{"imageSrc":"assets/img/ . $id . .jpg","second":"radi"}';
```

How it should be when send to JSON.parse()

```
 echo '{"imageSrc":"assets/img/2.jpg","second":"radi"}';
```

But i cant just add a variable or anything else but plain text to the JSON ?

The current page the AJAX get request calls for
PHP

```
require_once '../includes/db.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';

$dbCon = dbCon();
define("SQL", "SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$result = $dbCon->query(SQL);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $id = $row->id;

    //HOW DO I PARSE A VARIABLE INTO THIS JSON STRING BEFORE AJAX GETS IT??
    echo '{"imageSrc":"assets/img/2.jpg","second":"radi"}';
}
```

EDIT: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is a php function that dodes this thanks to [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) for the information

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
The above example will output:

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Comment: `JSON` is just a text representation of some data structure. Build your data structure at will then use the PHP function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get the text to be sent back to the browser. **Don't generate JSON by hand!**

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
$id = $row->id;

//in this way
echo '{"imageSrc":"assets/img/'.$id.'.jpg","second":"radi"}';
```

}

php dose not replace the variable value when you put it in single quotes

```
$var = "some text";
echo 'hi $var'; //output : hi $var
echo "hi $var"; //output : hi some text
```

or you can put your data inside an array and convert it to json like this

```
$arr = ["imageSrc"=>"assets/img/".$id.".jpg","second"=>"radi"];
echo json_encode($arr);
```